# connection refused with nfs server

Tags: nfs

I have an issue with NFS.
I have two rhel4 servers. sys1 and sys2.
I have a directory exported from sys1 and sys2 is the nfs client trying to access the mount.
I'm able to mount, but after a certain amount of time I get 
"RPC: Remote system error: Connection refused."
and then I restart nfs services, quotas, deamon, mountd and lockd.
Then it works fine again.

Any way to fix this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any firewall with timeouts between sys1 and sys2?